# Difference in timeinmillis in Browser and Java Server running in Two different timezones

Tags: javascript, java, timezone

Will there be any difference in current time milliseconds obtained using javascript code executed in machine which is in Timezone1 and Java code executed in machine which is in Timezone2 ?

Here's my sample code for this use case.

```
new Date().getTime();
```

using the above code, I get the current time in milliseconds. My machine is in IST

In the same time, my friend executes the below code in his machine which is in PDT.

```
public class Time
{
 public static void main(String args[])
 {
  System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
 }
}
```

When we both the executes the code at the same time. We are getting a difference of around 40 secs.

Am I missing something in this understanding?

Comment: You can set your local clock to anything, so you can never assume the same time on any computers, regardless of time zones (always use UTC and don't worry about time zones).  Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Could it be that the system clocks in your and your friend's machine are not really in sync? Unless you're both synchronizing your system clocks from a central location (or between each other), there's some inevitable drift between your clocks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there will be a difference in normal circumstances, i.e. if each system's clock is set to the correct time zone, and also if the client code is consistent:

- Uses local time, not UTC.
- Uses the Date object's default constructor, which returns the current date/time

Obviously the true difference will be inaccurate if the date is not retrieved at the same moment on both machines.